# Mercedes engine sump replacement

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz, oil-pan

Have a Mercedes R class that needs the engine oil sump replaced, I have the parts, would anyone know either the best way to go about such a repair or know of someone capable.  Mercedes price was stellar to say the least,

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm sure the best way is going to be to pull the engine, but I've never worked on an MB before, so couldn't tell you for sure.

Comment: 3 possibilities come to mind : @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 ‘s suggestion, OR lifting the engine sufficiently that it may come out the front once radiator etc is removed OR dropping / removing all the subframe / suspension - which means it all has to be re-aligned afterwards. Note not got one and not done it so it’s a wag ... oh and as for time guess and multiply by three...

Comment: @SolarMike - time estimate x3 ... sounds like what my wife suggests for me :o)

Comment: In my opinion, oil sumps are difficult to change because normally you wouldn't change one for the entire life of a car. There are some jobs that are economically feasible to do yourself Others that require equipment and expertise that is hard for a amateur mechanic to muster. Maybe you'll get lucky and it'll be easy to replace without taking half the car apart. The thought of removing an replacing a modern (i assume) MB engine makes me want to get a second job to pay someone else to do it. Cheers if you take this on yourself. Double cheers if you have a functioning vehicle at the end.

Comment: @TimNevins changed a few sumps due to damage, removed, cut and re-welded others as part of engine changes or conversions...